# when Verb DO is not used as an auxiliary verb, it changes to does just the

Tags: word-choice, verbs

> My wife always does what I say.

> My wife always do as I say.

What is the correct sentence? Should I use *does* or *do*, when *do* is not an auxiliary verb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it changes to "does", because all lexical verbs acquire "s" at the end in the third-person singular present-tense form:

> My wife always **does** as I say.
>
> My wives always **do** as I say. (If you [live in Saudi Arabia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamy_in_Saudi_Arabia))

This rule is only broken in very rare situations, for instance, in poetry, in order to retain the meter:

> Turned are those lights from me, who fondly yet
>   Past joys, vain loves, and buried hopes **regret**.
>   (Charles Lamb)

The quoted poem is the only example that I have been able to spot so far. And even here I've been proven wrong: see the comment by StoneyB below.

Hence, this rule is not broken even in poetry.

Comment: *Regret* is used there because *who* refers to first-person *me*--***I** regret the joys, loves and hopes.*

Comment: @StoneyB - Thank you for your insight. It is valuable for me, who sometimes yet post(s?) a wrong thing or two in my (his?) answer. I am glad that Charles Lamb was grammatically right here.